# Maven project won't run

Tags: java, maven

this is my first attempt in making a maven project. Usually I just create regular Java projects, but this time I need to use Firebase so I had to resort to maven dependencies. For testing purposes the application only establishes connection with Firebase and get a reference to the project's real time database. The problem is my code won't even run, I'm using NetBeans on Windows 10 and when I try to run, the following message appear: `Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project SEMS: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)`. Thank you.

So far I have tried:

1. Deleting NetBeans Cache
2. Run mvn clean install

Here is my **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>SEMS</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the debug log:

```
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\Alex\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\Alex\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project br.com:SEMS:jar:1.0: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix exec from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix exec to org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin from repository central
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin to 1.6.0 from repository central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: br.com:SEMS:jar:1.0
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [exec:exec]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SEMS 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix exec from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix exec to org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin from repository central
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin to 1.6.0 from repository central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       br.com:SEMS:1.0
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [test]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <addOutputToClasspath default-value="true">${addOutputToClasspath}</addOutputToClasspath>
  <addResourcesToClasspath default-value="false">${addResourcesToClasspath}</addResourcesToClasspath>
  <async default-value="false">${exec.async}</async>
  <asyncDestroyOnShutdown default-value="true">${exec.asyncDestroyOnShutdown}</asyncDestroyOnShutdown>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <classpathScope default-value="runtime">${exec.classpathScope}</classpathScope>
  <commandlineArgs>${exec.args}</commandlineArgs>
  <executable>${exec.executable}</executable>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <longClasspath default-value="false">${exec.longClasspath}</longClasspath>
  <longModulepath default-value="true">${exec.longModulepath}</longModulepath>
  <outputFile>${exec.outputFile}</outputFile>
  <pluginDependencies default-value="${plugin.artifacts}"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${exec.skip}</skip>
  <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
  <testSourceRoot>${testSourceRoot}</testSourceRoot>
  <toolchain default-value="jdk">${exec.toolchain}</toolchain>
  <workingDirectory>${exec.workingdir}</workingDirectory>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.grpc:grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for io.grpc:grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.netty:netty-codec-http2/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for io.netty:netty-codec-http2/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.grpc:grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for io.grpc:grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.netty:netty-codec-http2/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for io.netty:netty-codec-http2/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=266, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=63, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=6, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=162, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=301, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=11}
[DEBUG] br.com:SEMS:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]    com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:jar:5.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.3:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:jar:1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:jar:1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]             org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]             commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]             commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.api:api-common:jar:1.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.8.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.8.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:jar:1.15.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:jar:1.15.0:compile
[DEBUG]             joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.2:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.api:gax:jar:1.16.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.5.1:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:1.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-iam-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-http:jar:1.15.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]                org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.11:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.api:gax-httpjson:jar:0.33.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev114-1.23.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:jar:0.33.0-beta:compile
[DEBUG]          io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.7.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.15.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.5.1:compile
[DEBUG]             io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]                io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]             io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.16.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.google.auto.value:auto-value:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.3:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1beta1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[DEBUG]          io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:1.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]             io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]                com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.2:compile
[DEBUG]                com.google.instrumentation:instrumentation-api:jar:0.4.3:compile
[DEBUG]                io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.10.0:compile
[DEBUG]                io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics:jar:0.10.0:compile
[DEBUG]             io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]             io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]                io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]          io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]             io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) @ SEMS ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=93, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=39, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=1, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=78, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=137, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=2}
[DEBUG] org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.6.0:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[DEBUG]             org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]          org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.6.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) addOutputToClasspath = true
[DEBUG]   (f) addResourcesToClasspath = false
[DEBUG]   (f) async = false
[DEBUG]   (f) asyncDestroyOnShutdown = true
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = C:\Users\Alex\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SEMS
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathScope = runtime
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/Alex/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) longClasspath = false
[DEBUG]   (f) longModulepath = true
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginDependencies = [org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.6.0:, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:compile, org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: br.com:SEMS:1.0 @ C:\Users\Alex\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SEMS\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@1968a49c
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) toolchain = jdk
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.840 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-08T19:53:08-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) on project SEMS: The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) on project SEMS: The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**mvn install** output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SEMS 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SEMS ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SEMS ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SEMS ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Alex\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SEMS\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SEMS ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ SEMS ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ SEMS ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ SEMS ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Alex\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SEMS\target\SEMS-1.0.jar to C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository\br\com\SEMS\1.0\SEMS-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Alex\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SEMS\pom.xml to C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository\br\com\SEMS\1.0\SEMS-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.953 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-08T19:56:51-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Maybe usefull:

1. Running on NetBeans 8.2
2. OS is Windows 10 PRO 64bits
3. Maven version installed is 3.5

Comment: What is the maven command you used to try and execute the program?

Comment: It looks like NB did not provide the main class to the maven exec plugin. Try this: Open your file with main() class, and press shift-F6 (or select run option from mouse context menu). This should execute correct maven exec goal telling maven where is the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the exception at the end of the build (eg: `mvn -e install`):

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
```

You are missing the `executable` parameter as described here: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#executable

The `pom.xml` you are referencing in your question does not contains the plugin.

You should start with that:

- if you try to execute `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec`, then you'll need to pass the executable and other stuff using `-Dexecutable=path/to/executable`.
- if you try to execute it during the build, then you'll need appropriate plugin descriptor: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html